# Повтор участка функции в случае неудачи

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam-web-api

Мне нужно в случае ошибки выполнять функцию снова N раз

```
offer.accept(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        logger.error("Не Смог Принять Оффер: " + err.message);
        // вот тут мне нужно по повторно запустить функцию offer.accept
    } else {
        logger.info("Принял Оффер");
        dellmoney();
        logger.info("C Баланса Пользователя Списанно " + parserub + " Руб.");
        userbalans = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понял пример. Что мешает повторно вызвать `offer.accept` с темиже параметрами?

Comment: ммм , боюсь дублирования ........ , должен же быть нормальный способ

Answer (score 4):

Вынесите анонимную функцию в переменную, и наслаждайтесь жизнью:

```
var count = 0;    // счётчик попыток
var maxTries = 3; // не более 3
var handleAccept = function(err) {
    if(err) {
        logger.error("Не смог принять оффер: " + err.message);
        if( count++ < maxTries) offer.accept( handleAccept);        
    } else {
        logger.info("Принял оффер");
        dellmoney();
        logger.info("C баланса пользователя списано " + parserub + " руб.");
        userbalans = 0;
    }
}

offer.accept( handleAccept);
```